Look up and Match
I have two spreadsheets the first only has 2 columns which have the names of football clubs (A) & their home stadiums (B).
The second spreadsheet is where I input various fixtures, when I enter the home team name I want their home stadium to appear a column further along the sheet.
I'm usually decent with Excel Formula but this one is beating me
Is there a relevant formula?
Thank you in anticipation
I've used various VLOOKUP and MATCH formula but nothing is working for me.

add some example data and expected result

You either use INDEX/MATCH or VLOOKUP; Say you input the team name in Cell A2, you can use following in B2: =VLOOKUP(A2 , Sheet1!A1:B50 , 2), where Sheet1!A1:B50) is the range of your teams and their home stadiums. If you're using Excel 21 or 365, I recommend using XLOOKUP.

Try:
=VLOOKUP(A2, 'Spreadsheet1'!$A$2:$B$100, 2, FALSE)
Where A2 is the cell that has the Home Team Name that you want to look up
'Spreadsheet1'!$A$2:$B$100 is the table that you are using to lookup the value
2 is to return the second column

Thank you very much indeed - problem sorted now.

@FrancisSharps could you accept/upvote the answer if it helped

Your problem should be fixed by index match any version of the excel you use.
if you use excel 365 then xlookup will be super easy for you.
=Index(firstsheet:columnB,Match(secondsheet:hometeam_name,firstsheet:columnA,0))
=Xlookup(secondsheet:hometeam_name,firstsheet:columnA,firstsheet:columnB)

Thank you very much indeed - problem sorted now.
